# Why I cannot save mutate result in r?

Tags: r

This should be a simple question. I tried to rank "date" within each group (name) and save the rank output as rank_date.

However, I kept receiving the error "Error in df %>% group_by(name) %>% rank_date <- mutate(df, rank = order(score,  : could not find function "%>%<-""

```
df = data.frame(name=c("A","A","A","B","C","D"), score = c("03/21/2021", "04/21/2021", "05/21/2021", "06/21/2021","07/21/2021","03/21/2021"))
df$score = as.Date(df$score,"%m/%d/%Y")
df %>% 
    group_by(name)%>% 
  rank_date<-mutate(df, rank=order(score, decreasing=TRUE))
```

Comment: your mutate is not correct i.e. `df %>% group_by(name) %>%mutate(rank_date = order(score, decreasing = TRUE))`

Comment: Hi @akrun, I tried what you said. "rank_date<-mutate(rank_date =order(score, decreasing=TRUE))" and the new error is "Error in order(score, decreasing = TRUE) : object 'score' not found".

Answer (score 4):

You should place the final object, that should store the result, at the beginning:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(name=c("A","A","A","B","C","D"), score = c("03/21/2021", "04/21/2021", "05/21/2021", "06/21/2021","07/21/2021","03/21/2021"))
df$score = as.Date(df$score,"%m/%d/%Y")
df <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(rank_date = order(score, decreasing = TRUE))

df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   name [4]
#>   name  score      rank_date
#>   <chr> <date>         <int>
#> 1 A     2021-03-21         3
#> 2 A     2021-04-21         2
#> 3 A     2021-05-21         1
#> 4 B     2021-06-21         1
#> 5 C     2021-07-21         1
#> 6 D     2021-03-21         1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Similar problem... The rank_date variable was not saved to the datafrme? When I run names(df), the variable was not there...

Comment: Thanks@Daniel. It works if we don't consider saving it to the data frame...

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought the final _object_ (not the _variable_) should have the name. simply change the name in the `mutate()`, I'll update the example.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment should be either at the top (`<-`).  If we need to update the same object, do the assignment to the same object 'df'

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(rank_date = order(score, decreasing = TRUE))  %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  name  score      rank_date
#  <chr> <date>         <int>
#1 A     2021-03-21         3
#2 A     2021-04-21         2
#3 A     2021-05-21         1
#4 B     2021-06-21         1
#5 C     2021-07-21         1
#6 D     2021-03-21         1
```

---

or at the end (`->`) to an object

```
df %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(rank = order(score, decreasing = TRUE)) %>%
   ungroup -> df
```